# ¿ Cómo incrementar la velocidad de mi objeto en Unity cuando tenga cierta puntuación?

Tags: unity3d

Lo que estoy intentando es que mi objeto logre mayor velocidad conforme el usuario logra mayor puntuación, por ejemplo, cuando pase la barrera de los 20 puntos vaya más rápido, y cuando pase los 40 un poco más ... y así.

Tengo los scripts de `contador` y de velocidad de la bola uniforme que funcionan pero no soy capaz de hacer que si contador es > a tanto la velocidad incremente pues son 2 scripts diferentes y no he tocado mucho Unity, y no consigo hacerlo de ninguna manera.

**Script de contador**

`public class Contador : MonoBehaviour {`

```
public GUIText tiempocontrol; //
public float contador=0;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){

    //  GameObject halo = Instantiate(HaloPrefab) as GameObject;

    if ( col.gameObject.name == "Cube") {
        //  Destroy (col.gameObject);
        //halo.transform.SetParent (transform, false);
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        contador++;
    }
```

** Script de velocidad uniforme de la bola**

`var velocidad:int = 10;`

```
function Update () {

    transform.Translate(new Vector3(1,0,0) * velocidad * Time.deltaTime);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que veo es que tienes los dos scripts en lenguajes distintos: el primero en C# y el segundo en JavaScript. Te traduzco el segundo a C# para que la comunicación entre ellos sea más sencilla:

```
public class VelocidadBola : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float velocidad = 10f;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f) * velocidad * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Luego, en la clase `Contador` ya que el campo contador lo estás incrementando en 1 cada vez, mejor lo convertiría en un `int`.

```
public int contador;
```

Si los dos componentes están vinculados al mismo objeto, puedes acceder a ellos mediante el método `GetComponent<NombreComponente>()`. De esta forma, en el script `Contador`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if ( col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        contador++;

        if (contador == 20)
        {
            // Accedes al otro componente y cambias la velocidad
            GetComponent<VelocidadBola>().velocidad += 5f;
        }
    }
```

Si quieres que, por ejemplo, la bola aumente la velocidad de 5 en cinco cada vez que el contador sea un múltiplo de 20, como parece sugerir tu pregunta, podrías usar este código:

```
if (contador % 20 == 0)
{
    // Accedes al otro componente y cambias la velocidad
    GetComponent<VelocidadBola>().velocidad += 5f;
}
```

Comment: Vale, funciona, muchas gracias!